# Deleting Image file create a 0 byte file with same name remain

Tags: android, image

When I delete a file from gallery, it will delete but a file with the same name of image will be created with 0 byte size! That file will be displayed as a broken image in gallery! Help me please!

```
public void browse(View v)
{
    //This Method is for Browse Button OnClick to get an Image
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            File imgFile = new  File(selectedImagePath);
            //Deleting Image
            imgFile.delete();
            //Update Android Gallery to remove Image immediately
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] { imgFile.getAbsolutePath() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        }
                    }
                );
        }

    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

[image]

Here is my whole class:
(browse() method will get an image and start() method will compress it and save as a new file and then try to delete the original image where the problem appear:

```
public class Lab extends Activity {

int counter = 0;
long lastModDate;
public static String parent;
public static int deg = 0; 

public static String f_or = "";
public static String f_ta = "";
public static String f_original_Image_dim = "";
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;
Timer timer1;
Bitmap myBitmap;
int currentFormula = 3;
TouchImageView iv1;
TextView l1;
Button btn3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lab);
    l1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtl1);
    iv1 = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_selectedpic);

}


public void zard(View v)
{
    l1.setText("F = A");
    currentFormula = 1;
}
public void ghermez(View v)
{
    l1.setText("F = B");
    currentFormula = 2;
}
public void sabz(View v)    
{
    l1.setText("F = C");
    currentFormula = 3;
}

public void next(View v)    
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Lab.this, Resoflab.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
public void browse(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            File imgFile = new  File(selectedImagePath);
            lastModDate = imgFile.lastModified();
            try
            {
                if(imgFile.exists()){
                    counter = 0;
                    Resoflab.de = 0;
                    System.gc();
                    BitmapFactory.Options optionss = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    optionss.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    optionss.inScaled = false;
                    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),optionss);
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath);
                    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
                    deg = rotationInDegrees;
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    if (rotation != 0f) {
                        matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
                        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    }
                    f_original_Image_dim = myBitmap.getWidth() + "*" + myBitmap.getHeight();
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                    //TouchImageview not displayed image after setImageBitmap so I set setZoom(1) after some miliseconds and its OK now
                    //This is why I used timer
                    timer1 = new Timer();
                    timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {           
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TimerMethod1();
                        }
                    }, 0, 300);
                    //iv2.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Lab.this,getResources().getString(R.string.khateyezir)  + "\n\n" +  ee.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}

private void TimerMethod1()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick1);
}
private Runnable Timer_Tick1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            counter++;
            iv1.setZoom(1);
            if(counter == 4)
            {
                counter = 0;
                timer1.cancel();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
};

public void start(View v)
{
    try
    {
        if(selectedImagePath.contains("_optimizes_"))
        {
            //Toast that Image had been optimized
            Toast.makeText(Lab.this,getResources().getString(R.string.isoptimized),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        String fm = "C";
        if(currentFormula == 2)fm = "B";
        if(currentFormula == 1)fm = "A";
        File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
        if(file.exists() == false)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Lab.this,getResources().getString(R.string.hasdeleted),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        parent = file.getParent();

        String name = file.getName();
        String extension = FileUtils.getExtension(name);

        String fileNameWithOutExt = FileUtils.removeExtension(name);
        String Targetname = fileNameWithOutExt + "_optimizes_" + fm + "." + extension;
        String TargetPath = parent + "/" + Targetname;  


        File Tfile = new File(parent, Targetname);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(Tfile);

        if(currentFormula == 3)
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outStream);
        else if(currentFormula == 2)
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outStream);
        else myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        Tfile.setLastModified(lastModDate);
        //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Tfile)));
        //SingleMediaScanner sc = new SingleMediaScanner(Lab.this, Tfile);

        String Tfilepath = Tfile.getAbsolutePath();
        String filepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        //HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
        file.delete();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[] { Tfilepath, filepath}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        //now visible in gallery
                    }
                }
            );
        //f_ta = TargetPath;
        //f_original_Image_dim = selectedImagePath;
        //Intent i = new Intent(Lab.this, Resoflab.class);
        //startActivity(i);
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Lab.this,getResources().getString(R.string.khateyezir)  + "\n\n" +  ee.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    //btn3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String ret = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return ret;
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {        
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }            
    return 0;    
}
```

}

Comment: you are still not closing the cursor and using `file.getAbsolutePath()` and why are you using `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile` two times , you are passing String Array use `new String[] { Tfile.getAbsolutePath(),file.getAbsolutePath() }` instead

Comment: I closed the cursor as you can see, use string instead of file.getAbsolutePath and usig MediaScannerConnection.scanFile once but still the problem persist :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after deleting a picture for example by calling myfile.delete() we have to remove it from mediaStore and this is function of removing a file from media store:

```
public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
String canonicalPath;
try {
    canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
} catch (IOException e) {
    canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
}
final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {canonicalPath});
if (result == 0) {
    final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
        contentResolver.delete(uri,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal check it out, we should not use mediaScan or send Broadcast for deleted file we just should remove it from mediaStore   mediascan or sending broadcast is useful when we  create and save a bitmap  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            File imgFile = new  File(selectedImagePath);
            String imgFilePath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath(); // <-- Add this
            //Deleting Image
            imgFile.delete();
            //Update Android Gallery to remove Image immediately
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] { imgFilePath }, null,    // <-- change this
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Try using this mechanism, which will update the gallery:

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Add this to your application manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
        <data android:scheme="file" /> 
    </intent-filter>
```

**Edit:**

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    if( uri == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if( cursor != null ){
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String path = cursor.getString(column_index); //<-- Add this
        cursor.close(); //<-- Add this
        return path;    //<-- change this
    }
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem persist. 0 byte file created again and displayed in gallery

Comment: in this solution android does not recognize deleted image immediately, but after minutes the image will hide and the broken image come again :(

Comment: Yes I have added this permission too.

Comment: try closing the cursor before returning

Comment: I append it to end of my question

Comment: you already have `File file = new File(selectedImagePath);` open and again you are doing `File mfile = new File(selectedImagePath);`   so i suggest your to not use `File mfile = new File(selectedImagePath);` and use `file.delete()` when you want to delete the file after your operations

Comment: I used file as you said and update my class code but still the problem persist